# html search and replace preserving html tags

Tags: java, html-parser

I'm looking for a Java based html parser which can search and replace text preserving html tags. This question has been asked here before but the answers seems to be not hitting the target. There are few html parsers which I downloaded and wrote simple programs to see whether they can do the job. These include jsoup, Jericho, Java HTML parser etc. These can do a search but when it comes to replacing text preserving html tags, there is no way to do it.

I have read the complete thread for these posts:

[How to find/replace text in html while preserving html tags/structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856014/how-to-find-replace-text-in-html-while-preserving-html-tags-structure)

[html search and replace on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696600/html-search-and-replace-on-server-side)

If there are no such parser exists today, what is the best way for implementing one? If you have done something like this already, can you share the code?

Comment: Looks like you've missed this important point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856014/how-to-find-replace-text-in-html-while-preserving-html-tags-structure/1856634#1856634 What'd you say in reply? Isn't that a reason why you cant find "right" parser?

Comment: I hope you are referring to akaihola's reply. There is an issue with step 3 - it assumes that the string is found at position 1, 2 as the steps shows: The regex needed in 3. is #(\d+);stack\s+#(\d+);overflow\b and the replacement #\1;stack %\2;underflow

Comment: Did you find some solution or how did you get this done. Please share.

Answer (score 1):

The Jericho parser might help you. Has been around forever and works with malformed HTML.
http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html

Comment: Thank you, but jericho can replace only within a start tag and end tag. We can do that without any html parsers by simply doing a text search and replace.

Answer (score 1):

The Caja parser uses libhtmlparser, an HTML5 parser that deals well with tag soup containing embedded XML subtrees producing an `org.w3c.dom.DocumentFragment`, and has a renderer that produces well formed HTML.

The parser code is at http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/caja/parser/html/DomParser.java

The renderer code is at http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/caja/parser/html/Nodes.java