# Find text and elements with python and selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

When I go to a certain webpage I am trying to find a certain element and piece of text:

```
<span class="Bold Orange Large">0</span>
```

This didn't work: (It gave an error of compound class names or something...)

```
elem = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("Bold Orange Large")
```

So I tried this: (but I'm not sure it worked because I don't really understand the right way to do css selectors in selenium...)

```
elem = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("span[class='Bold Orange Large']")
```

Once I find the span element, I want to find the number that is inside...

```
num = elem.(what to put here??)
```

Any help with css selectors, class names, and finding element text would be great!!

Thanks.

EDIT:

My other problem is that there are multiple of those exact span elements but with different numbers inside..how can I deal with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're correct in your usage of css selectors! Also your first attempt was failing because there are spaces in the class name and selenium does not seem to be able to find standalone identifiers with spacing at all. I think that is a bad development practice to begin with, so its not your problem. Selenium itself does not include an html editor, because its already been done before.

Try looking here: [How to find/replace text in html while preserving html tags/structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856014/how-to-find-replace-text-in-html-while-preserving-html-tags-structure).

Also this one is relevant and popular as well: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)