# Search and replace HTML Text, not tags

Tags: python, html, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find/replace text in html while preserving html tags/structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856014/how-to-find-replace-text-in-html-while-preserving-html-tags-structure)

I want to search and replace through HTML text. I don't want to fiddle with the tags or their attributes, just the HTML text. How should I do that in Python?

Comment: Can you post the code that isn't working properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import lxml.etree as et
html=\
"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello HTML</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello 1</p>
    <p>Hello 2</p>
    <p>Hello 3</p>
    <p>Hello 4</p>
  </body>
</html>
"""
doc = et.fromstring(html)
for i in doc.xpath('.//p[contains(.,"Hello") and not(contains(.,"4"))]'):
    i.text='replaced'
print et.tostring(doc,pretty_print=True)
```

OUT:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello HTML</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>replaced</p>
    <p>replaced</p>
    <p>replaced</p>
    <p>Hello 4</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Re](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module. Or just use [replace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) function.

But Search and replace is very inefficient processing, if you need to replace on multiple keywords. You should better parse the structure via [beautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [lxml](http://lxml.de/), get the objects, and do some operations on the objects.