# How to get content (only) inside HTML tag up-to single level in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dom, html-parsing

TLDR: Need javascript solution to this question [Search and replace HTML Text, not tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134843/search-and-replace-html-text-not-tags)

I have been through lot of answers stating that not to use RegeX but no one has given exact solution to this. I want to loop through each DOM element on page. Lookup a word against its text and **substitute a HTML at the very same place of word**.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  function isJson(item) {
    item = typeof item !== "string"
        ? JSON.stringify(item)
          : item;
    try {
        item = JSON.parse(item);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }

    if (typeof item === "object" && item !== null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  function loop(elements, words) {
    elements.each(function(){
      element = $(this); 
      var text = element.html();
      for (k in words) {
   
        if(isJson(words[k])){
          defObj = JSON.parse(words[k]);
          for (var j = defObj["data"].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (defObj["data"][j]["definition"]) {
              liText = (defObj["data"][j]["wordtype"] ? defObj["data"][j]["wordtype"] : defObj["data"][j]["partOfSpeech"]) + ";  "+ defObj["data"][j]["definition"];
            }else{
              liText = defObj["data"][j]["translatedText"];
            }
          } 
        }else{
          liText = words[k];
        }

        li = '<li>'+liText+'</li>';
        ol = '<ol style="padding: 15px !important; padding-right: 0px !important; margin: 0 auto !important;">'+li+'</ol>';
        
        var regex = new RegExp('(\\b)'+k+'(\\b)', 'ig');
        // replace the matched word with the ol list created above.
        text = text.replace(regex, ol); 
      }

      if (element.html() !== text) {
          element.html(text);
      }
    })
  }

  function getElements(el) {
    return $(el).withinviewport();
  }

  chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(result) {
    //result is an object literal with words as key and its meaning as json string
    if (result) {
      loop($("li"), result);
      loop($("h5"), result);
      loop($("h6"), result);
    } 
  }); 
});
```

So far, the above code is doing great. But it misses following cases, Taking **settle** keyword as example, I don't want to match below cases, but my regex is matching these too.

```
1. <h5 title="this settle line should not match"> This settle line should match </h5>

2. <li> this settle line should match <div> this settle line should not match </div> </li>

3. <li> <a href="abc"> this settle line should not match </a> this settle line should match </li>

4. <h6> this settle line should match 
     <div> 
        something random without settle word, so should not match  
        <h6> this settle line should also not match </h6> 
     </div> 
   </h6>
```

These cases could be avoided if i want to replace with text. But for HTML it breaks the layout if something within the tag get matches. I am facing this issue from 2 years please help. I am open to any solution.

Comment: your snippet does not work, "" ReferenceError: $ is not defined "," do you use any javascript library? Can you give an example of the entire website before the change and the whole page after the change? Best as links to websites.

Answer (score 1):

My answer refers to the first part of the question, "do the same in javascript as in the python in the example: [Search and replace HTML Text, not tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134843/search-and-replace-html-text-not-tags)"

On this basis, you should figure out how to develop a solution that changes the content of tags as described in part 2 of the questions.

The code works but it's just a concept and requires refactoring.

```js
// the data:
var input = '<!DOCTYPE html>\
<html>\
    <head>\
    <title>Hello HTML</title>\
</head>\
<body>\
  <a href="#">abc</a>\
  <p>Hello 1</p>\
  <p>Hello 2</p>\
  <p>Hello 3</p>\
  <p>Hello 4</p>\
</body>\
</html>';


function string2xml(text) {
  try {
    var xml = null;
    if (window.DOMParser) {
      var parser = new DOMParser();
      xml = parser.parseFromString(text, 'text/xml');
      var foundErr = xml.getElementsByTagName('parsererror');
      if (!foundErr || !foundErr.length || !foundErr[0].childNodes.length) {
        return xml;
      }
      return null;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    ;
  }
}


// xml object input data:
var xmldoc = string2xml(input);


var out='';
out += '<!DOCTYPE html><html>';
// the head nodes:
out += xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].outerHTML;
out += '<body>\n';
// the body nodes:
var nodes=xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].children;
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
 if(nodes.item(i).nodeName == 'p') {
  regex=/^[^4]*$/;
         out += '<p>'+(nodes.item(i).innerHTML).replace(regex,"replaced")+'</p>\n';
        }
 else {
  out += nodes.item(i).outerHTML+'\n';
 }
}
out += '</body></html>';

// the output data:
console.log(out);
```