# How to change HTML tags preserving its contained content

Tags: html, replace, tags

Across multiple html files I have 217 instances of:

```
<p class="quote">“Lots of different quotes.”</p>
```

And want to bulk change them into:

```
<blockquote>
  <p>“Lots of different quotes.”</p>
</blockquote>
```

I was thinking of using regular expressions, until I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11230103/13963944), which discourages the use of regex. But the answer is quite old so I wonder if there is a new best approach.

I tried regex but I am not sure whether that is the most efficient method. I am using vscodium, but didn't immediately find relevant extensions.

Comment: Just try and compare (regex) speed with (document.body.querySelectorAll('p.quote'), checking is textContent of each item of list equal to 'Lots of different quotes')

Comment: Answering my own question, I'll be trying out BeautifulSoup to solve this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1856019/13963944.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using VSCodium the following regular expression captured most cases by replacing:

```
<p class="quote">([^<]+)</p>
```

or the following to include nested tags

```
<p class="quote">((?:[^<]+|<(?!/p>))*)</p>
```

with

```
<blockquote>\n\t\t\t<p>$1</p>\n\t\t</blockquote>
```